# Routing Network through OpenVPN: Network Lost

Tags: networking, openvpn, ip-address, static-routes

I am trying to route my traffic through OpenVPN server so that all traffic can go through the server and I access the internet through it. Here is my route table, looks like I lost my access to the network:

```
>>route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.8.1.0        10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.2.0        10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.3.0        10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.10.0.0       10.8.0.1        255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.11.0.0       10.8.0.1        255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
52.8.94.117     192.168.8.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp0s3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-5e059b344652
172.31.0.0      10.8.0.1        255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
```

caption:

- 52.8.94.117 is my open vpn public IP address which is routed to my home gateway..
- 10.8.0.1 is my internal vpn ip address assigned by tun0

Comment: And what routes do you _expect_ to see?

Comment: I want to access the internet from my client through the vpn server so that the world will see the ip address of the server itself. When pinging google.com under this setup nothing is returned @grawity